# wooCommerce - get shipping class from the Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking to write a snippet of code that will display a shortcode on the Product Page depending upon what the shipping class for that product is - if shipping class is "X" then display shortcode, else don't display.

I am having trouble figuring out how to retrieve the shipping class - what is the right way to call get_shipping_class() method.

(php novice)

I have tried something like:

```
$Set_shipping_class = 'furniture-oversized';

if ( $Set_shipping_class  === WC_Product::get_shipping_class()); {
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', ‘display_Shortcode’, 100 );
  function display_Shortcode() {
    echo do_shortcode('[phoeniixx-pincode-check]');
}              
        }
```

have also tried the following to get shipping class, but the bottom line kills my site:

```
$Set_shipping_class = 'furniture-oversized';
$_product = wc_get_product();
$shipclass = $_product->get_shipping_class(); //this line kills the site
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
$_product = wc_get_product();
$shipclass = $_product->get_shipping_class();
```

is the right way to go, but you need to pass the post id of the product in to `wc_get_product()`, so the first line should actually be:

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
```

not forgetting to set the $post_id variable first.